# Sending sms in broadcast receiver whithin service continue wrongly until reject call

Tags: android, android-service, android-broadcastreceiver, smsmanager

I have an app which send sms automatically when a call occur , but when a call ocuured sending sms started and continue multiple times until call reject , and it's wrong and i want to send just one time for each calling . Here is my code please help me

SmsService.java

```
public class SmsService extends Service {

public static
BroadcastReceiver mReceiver;

 public static class ServiceReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(final Context context, final Intent intent) {

        TelephonyManager telephony = (TelephonyManager)context.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
        telephony.listen(new PhoneStateListener(){
            @Override
            public void onCallStateChanged(int state, String incomingNumber) {
                super.onCallStateChanged(state, incomingNumber);
                //  System.out.println("incomingNumber : "+incomingNumber);
                TelephonyManager telephony = (TelephonyManager)context.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
                telephony.listen(new PhoneStateListener(){
                    @Override
                    public void onCallStateChanged(int state, String incomingNumber) {
                        super.onCallStateChanged(state, incomingNumber);
                        Log.d("callingggggggg","oopsssss");


                       sendSMS(incomingNumber,"hello",context);
                    }
                },PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_CALL_STATE);
            }
        },PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_CALL_STATE);

    }
}
```

SendSMS.java

```
private void sendSMS(String phoneNumber, String message, Context c) {
        try {
            SmsManager sms = SmsManager.getDefault();
            sms.sendTextMessage(phoneNumber,null,message,null,null);
            Toast.makeText(c, "SMS sent.",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        } catch (Exception e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
            Toast.makeText(c, "SMS sending failed...",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

    }

}
```

**NOTE :** first time i do register and Unregister my receiver in onCreate and onDestroy in my service class but after that change it into onResume and onPause in my main activity , none of them has no different.

onResume and onPause in Main activity

```
  @Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();

    IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter();
    filter.addAction("action");
    filter.addAction("android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED");
    mReceiver = new SmsService.ServiceReceiver();
    registerReceiver(mReceiver, filter);

     }

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();

    unregisterReceiver(mReceiver);

}
```

Manifest.xml

```
<service
        android:enabled="true"
        android:name=".SmsService"
        android:label="SmsService" >
    </service>

 <receiver android:name="com.example.mohammad.testsms.SmsService$ServiceReceiver" >
        <intent-filter >
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE" />
        </intent-filter>
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.NEW_OUTGOING_CALL" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

Answer (score 1):

Because you listen to so much state change action. maybe you can listen to only one action. 
You can

```
telephony.listen(new PhoneStateListener(){
                @Override
                public void onCallStateChanged(int state, String incomingNumber) {
                    super.onCallStateChanged(state, incomingNumber);
                    Log.d("callingggggggg","state:"+state);// here！！！！！！！


                   sendSMS(incomingNumber,"hello",context);
                }
            },PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_CALL_STATE);
```

and get which state only occur once . and switch that state.
hope that helps you.

Comment: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/TelephonyManager.html   You can get state info from this website.

Comment: I do this but there is no difference

Answer (score 0):

I solve my problem eventually thanks from @ihsan.gaozp for his write help to direct me to solving . what i did is switching between state of onCallstateChange method and in addition to this i define static boolean variable in my service , then control case of switch for sending sms in ringing sate and then set false this variable to prevent calling sms method after that , again set true in idle state to get permission for later call . here is what i've done :

```
 public  static boolean stateCall  = true ;

 @Override
            public void onCallStateChanged(int state, String incomingNumber) {
                super.onCallStateChanged(state, incomingNumber);

                switch (state) {
                    case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_RINGING:
                        if(stateCall){
                            Log.d("callingggggggg",state + "");
                            sendSms();
                            stateCall = false ;
                        }

                        break ;
                    case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_IDLE:
                        stateCall = true;
                        Log.d("DEBUG", "***********IDLE********");
                        break;

                }
```